# Category pagination not working in category.php please help me

Tags: categories, pagination

```
<div class="col-sm-8 main-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <?php
                $cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
                $cat_slug = cat_slug($cat_id);
                $query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page' => '1',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'category_name' => $cat_slug
                ));
                while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                     ?>
                    <div class="single-block">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" style="height: 285px; object-fit: cover;" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="paddingRight10 paddingTop20">
                                    <h3 style="font-size:1.5em;line-height:34px;margin-bottom:10px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                    <?php
                                        readMore(20);
                                     ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="loadMoreContent">
                <?php
                $cat_id = get_queried_object_id();
                $cat_slug = cat_slug($cat_id);
                $query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page' => '',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'offset' => '1',
                    'category_name' => $cat_slug
                ));
                while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
                 ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="single-block cat-block">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="img-box">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="news-title"><img style="object-fit:cover;" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="paddingTop10 paddingRight10">
                                    <h3 style="font-size:1.1em;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>


            </div>
            <div class="text-center paddingBottom20">
                <div class="pagination pagination-sm">


                    <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                            'screen_reader_text' => ' ', // this should hide the title
                            'prev_text'          => __( '&larr; পূর্ববর্তী', 'ourdesh' ),
                            'next_text'          => __( 'পরবর্তী &rarr;', 'ourdesh' ),
                            'before_page_number'=> '<b>',
                            'after_page_number'=> '</b>',
                            'show_all'=> false,

                            ) );
                    ?>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you use custom queries in there? Why don't you use the one created by WordPress?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress development! Code-only questions are highly discouraged. Please update your question and tell us more about your exact issue and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

> Category pagination not working in `category.php` please help me

Pagination is not working due to the fact that page executes the same queries every time.

From your OP code, it seems that you want to *style 1st post differently than other*.

**If I understood your question correctly,** you don't need to use custom queries, use the one created by WordPress -- the main query instead.

This may help.

```
  <?php 

  global $wp_query;

  if( have_posts() ){

        while( have_posts() ){

              the_post();

              if ( $wp_query->current_post == 0 ){  // Check if it is 1st post


                 // Markup for 1st post


              } 

              else {


                  // Markup for all other posts


              }   // End else

        }// End: while(have_posts())

  }   //End: if(have_posts()) 

 ?>

        <div class="text-center paddingBottom20">
                <div class="pagination pagination-sm">
                    <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                            'screen_reader_text' => ' ', // this should hide the title
                            'prev_text'          => __( '&larr; পূর্ববর্তী', 'ourdesh' ),
                            'next_text'          => __( 'পরবর্তী &rarr;', 'ourdesh' ),
                            'before_page_number'=> '<b>',
                            'after_page_number'=> '</b>',
                            'show_all'=> false,

                            ) );
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
```